# iPhone CAAnimation problem

Tags: iphone

I am getting the following errors when I try to use the CAAnimation constants, in a program I just wrote. I am able to run the "ViewTransitions" example (from the apple library, http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/index.html), and I do not see anything that has been done there, that I haven't :mad:.

P.S. - I did include QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h ..

"_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
      _kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut$non_lazy_ptr in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
          "_kCATransitionFromTop", referenced from:
              _kCATransitionFromTop$non_lazy_ptr in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
          "_kCATransitionPush", referenced from:
              _kCATransitionPush$non_lazy_ptr in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
          ".objc_class_name_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
              literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAMediaTimingFunction in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
          ".objc_class_name_CATransition", referenced from:
              literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CATransition in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
          "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
              _kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut$non_lazy_ptr in EMISNewsWebViewController.o

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, I am getting 5 errors in the following format(all related to inability of debugger to identify standard CAAnimation constants)
  
"_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
      _kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut$non_lazy_ptr in EMISNewsWebViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added QuartzCore.framework to link to your project.